# Simplifying a logarithmic equation

Tags: logarithms

How would one simplificate the following statement, resulting in only one log-term, if this is even possible. Thanks in advance.

$log(x)^{A}\cdot log(x)^{-\frac{1}{A-1}} - log(x)^{-\frac{1}{A-1}}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write $$\frac{\log(x)^A-1}{\log(x)^{\frac{1}{A-1}}}$$

Comment: Seems understandable, however changing it slightly to $log(x)^{A}\cdot log(x)^{-\frac{A}{A-1}} - log(x)^{-\frac{1}{A-1}}$ would change it all together right.